# problems with matlib in R.4.0.2

Tags: r

hello i tried to install the package

`install.packages('matlib', dependencies=TRUE, type="source", repos="https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=matlib")`

returns the following error:  " Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=matlib/src/contrib:
no fue posible abrir la URL 'https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=matlib/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘matlib’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)"

then try the following code:

`install.packages('matlib', dependencies=TRUE, type="source")`

and it asks me to install dependency and one of them the first  `RcppEigen`

when trying to install it even from the terminal

`sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcppeigen`
I have here the problem asks me for `r-api- 3.5` that I cannot install it and I do not want to uninstall r-base because I have a lot of packages that I occupy

Comment: R 3.5 and R  4.0 are not compatible

Comment: If you're using R-4.0.2, can you try `install.packages("RcppEigen")` *in R* instead of the OS-level package management? I know there are a lot of good reasons for relying on debian's `apt-get` for R packages, but perhaps this option will work.

Comment: if in that case I can install as matlib?  @r2evans I've already tried

Comment: `install.packages(c("RcppEigen","matlib"), type="source", dependencies = TRUE, repo=...)`?

Comment: I think you said you tried `install.packages("matlib")` and `apt-get install r-cran-rcppeigen`, but not `install.packages("RcppEigen")`.

Comment: What repository did it occupy?